# Warning Redefinition of typedef 'ElementType' is a C11 feature

Tags: iphone, ipad

I got this warning `Redefinition of typedef 'ElementType' is a C11 feature`

```
typedef NSString* ElementType;

extern NSString* const Element_Type_Exit;
extern NSString* const Element_Type_NOTExit;
extern NSString* const Element_Type_Enter;
```

how to fix the warning! i am looking for my application warning free! can any one advice me to fix this warning.

@thanks in advance

Comment: Does the warning also occur if you use a different name, e.g `TheElementType`?

Answer (score 2):

You must have another typedef for ElementType in your code. Therefore the warning of the compiler that you redefine it here.